# TypeError: Cannot read property 'blob.user.name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
    
const Blog = ({ blog }) => {
    const [ visible, setVisible ] = useState(false);
    const hideWhenVisible = { display: visible ? 'none' : '' };
    const showWhenVisible = { display: visible ? '' : 'none' };

    const toggleVisible = () => {
        setVisible(!visible);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div style={hideWhenVisible}>
                <strong>{blog.title}</strong> - {blog.author}{' '}
                <button onClick={toggleVisible}>view</button>
            </div>
            <div style={showWhenVisible}>
                <strong>{blog.title}</strong> - {blog.author}{' '}
                <button onClick={toggleVisible}>hide</button>
                <br />
                <strong>{blog.url}</strong>
                <br />
                <strong>
                    {blog.likes}
                    <button>like</button>
                </strong>
                <br />
                <strong>{blog.user.name}</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Blog;
```

[image]

[image]

Above is the data i want access and the type of error am getting

Comment: Where is the `console.log` related to the image that you attach to the question?

Comment: Look at the definition for `Blog`. Does it say `user` can be undefined? If so, you need to figure out how your UI will handle this case. If it can never happen, you can assert it by throwing an Error, and the TypeError will go away (or you can use the `?.` operator, but I prefer throwing).

Answer (score 0):

to remove error you can change
`blog.user.name` to `blog.user?.name`. But to be sure just log whole blog object on top of the component and check what you got. Probably on first render you're getting an empty object and it's cause an error.

Comment: Thansks... blog.user?.name SOLVED it for me.